# VBS using a variable string to reference an array name gives Type mismatch 'ubound' Code: 800A000D

Tags: arrays, variables, vbscript

I have 40 arrays named, for example, **arrOne**, **arrTwo**, **arrThree**, etc. So:

```
Dim arrOne

arrOne = Array("word","Cat","Dog","Bob")

' I can lbound and ubound this array... **BUT!!!**

strChooseOne = "arrOne"

For I = 0 to ubound(strChooseOne)

' ***do stuff***

Next
```

This results in an error:

> Type mismatch 'ubound'
>   Code: 800A000D

Probably since strChooseOne is a string variable containing "arrOne" whereas arrOne is an actual array...

I need to cycle through 500 items, that will reference 1 of the 40 arrays, in any order... I'd rather not have to duplicate the ' ***do stuff*** code 40 times, checking against each array...
I'd like to use the For ... Next loop code once, changing the name of the array each time through...

I have googled the error code but nothing seems relevant.

Comment: You need nested arrays.

Comment: 40? Wow, that’s a large overhead. Like @omegastripes has already suggested you might want to consider using nested arrays or a `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: The error is because `UBound()` expects an `Array` variable but it is being passed a `String`. If you want to dyamically evaluate the array variables you’ll need to use `Eval()` to evaluate the variable name in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below example:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim aData
Dim aTmp
Dim i
Dim j
Dim s

' Populate main array with 40 nested arrays of random elements quantity
Randomize
ReDim aData(39)
For i = 0 To 39
    aTmp = Array()
    Do
        ReDim Preserve aTmp(UBound(aTmp) + 1)
        aTmp(UBound(aTmp)) = "[" & Right("0" & i, 2) & Chr(65 + UBound(aTmp)) & "]"
    Loop Until Rnd > 0.55
    aData(i) = aTmp
Next

' Make processing you need
s = ""
For i = 0 To 39
    For j = 0 To UBound(aData(i))
        ' ***do stuff***
        s = s & aData(i)(j)
    Next
    s = s & vbCrLf
Next

WScript.Echo s
```